# ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django and trying to create a web page with two submit buttons one for login and one for registration.
After adding model classes for a database this error occurred. (pre model code commented with sign #). 
Cannot find any answers online or in Django documentation for this issue.

*authentication.html*

```
<form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom-mb-4">Login User</legend>
                        {{Lform|crispy}}
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" name="login">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="content-selection">
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <legend class="border-bottom-mb-4">Register User</legend>
                        {{Rform|crispy}}
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" name="register">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Below is views.py

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import login, register


def home(request):
    return render(request,"authentication/home.html",{})

def authentication(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        Lform=login(request.POST)
        Rform=register(request.POST)
        if Lform.is_valid():
            email = Lform.cleaned_data.get('Email')
            password = Lform.cleaned_data.get('Password')
            messages.success(request,email+' loged in')
            return redirect('home')
        elif Rform.is_valid():
            name=Rform.cleaned_data.get('name')
            email = Rform.cleaned_data.get('email')
            password = hash(Rform.cleaned_data.get('password'))
            confirm_password = hash(Rform.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password'))
            if password == confirm_password:
                messages.success(request,name+' registered')
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'password dont match')
                return redirect('authentication')
    else:
        print('page')
        Lform=login()
        Rform=register()
    return render(request,"authentication/authentication.html", {'Lform':Lform,'Rform':Rform})
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from .models import Authentication

class login(forms.Form):
    Email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email'}))###Capital E in email for login
    Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())###Capital P in Password for login

class register(forms.Form,forms.ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = Authentication
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
        labels = {
            'name':'Name',
            'email':'Email-id',
            'password':'Password',
        }
    ####name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Name'}))
    ####email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email'}))
    #####password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    confirm_password =forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(register, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['confirm_password'].label = "Confirm Password"
```

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
class Authentication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key = True,max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/auth/
Django Version: 2.1.7
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
ModelForm has no model class specified.
Exception Location: D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in __init__, line 285
Python Executable:  D:\Python\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2''''

''''D:\Python\login\authentication\views.py in authentication
        Rform=register() ...
▶ Local vars
D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py in __init__
            raise ValueError('ModelForm has no model class specified.') ...
▶ Local vars
```

I have another issue i.e. to add login button to model. For that, I have to change name in forms.py class login. Cannot figure out meta tag for changing field name when getting input in forms.py when getting attribute from models.py.

Comment: Try changing ```meta``` to ```Meta``` in forms.py

Comment: also your form doesn't need to inherit from `Form`, `ModelForm` already does that.